# Arctan Identity, impact of (-1)

Tags: calculus, trigonometry

I am slightly unsure of a basic trig identity operation.

Is the below true?
$$
\arctan \Big(\frac{-y+u}{-x+c}\Big) = \arctan \Big(\frac{y-u}{x-c}\Big)
$$

Or is it instead this...?
$$
\arctan \Big(\frac{-y+u}{-x+c}\Big) = -\arctan \Big(\frac{y-u}{x-c}\Big)
$$

Or is it instead something else...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $$\frac{-y+u}{-x+c}=\frac{-(y-u)}{-(x-c)}=\frac{y-u}{x-c},$$ so the former is correct.